# Compiler errors with typedef c++

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, header

I'm currently working on meshing together some declarations for ntdll functions from various exploit-db files in order to create a keylogger (educationally).
   I tried searching around on here, and the general web. I couldn't find anything similar enough to where I could understand how to use it to fix my issue. I apologize if there's a duplicate, I couldn't find anything related.

I put these in a header file, and when trying to compile them I get all sorts of errors related to the typedefs within the header, I get error messages mentioning decltype, and I'll admit I can't seem to understand it at all. I've never really messed with header stuff or with decltype, I searched around, but still can't really understand it. The errors occur with this:

```
typedef (NTSTATUS) (WINAPI *LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx)
(
    OUT PHANDLE hThread,
    IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    IN LPVOID ObjectAttributes,
    IN HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    IN LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
    IN LPVOID lpParameter,
    IN BOOL CreateSuspended,
    IN DWORD StackZeroBits,
    IN DWORD SizeOfStackCommit,
    IN DWORD SizeOfStackReserve,
    OUT LPVOID lpBytesBuffer
);

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI *lNtAllocVirtMem)(
    IN  HANDLE  ProcessHandle,
    IN  PVOID   *BaseAddress,
    IN  PULONG  ZeroBits,
    IN  PSIZE_T RegionSize,
    IN  ULONG   AllocationType,
    IN  ULONG   Protect
);
```

The other error in the main.cpp is: (sorry about the long line)

```
lNtAllocVirtMem pNtAllocateVirtualMemory=(lNtAllocVirtMem)GetProcAddress(LoadLibaryA("ntdll.dll"),"NtAllocateVirtualMemory");
```

My errors are(I get a double of both):

```
error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'
error: typedef 'NTSTATUS' is initialized (use decltype instead)
```

I would like to know how to solve these (as I plan on adding more),  and more importantly, how can I make sure I don't get these from here on out?

Comment: Are you compiling in gcc? This is compiler specific code and so you'll probably have to look up the specs for your compiler on proper usage.

Comment: A Google search reveals that, basically, `NTSTATUS` is [Microsoftese for a `long`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230357.aspx). As such, the typedef makes no sense. It is not clear what exactly you intend to alias, using the typedef. If `NTSTATUS` is the return value from the function, it shouldn't be in parenthesis. More Googling reveals that `WINAPI` [is Microsoftese for `__stdcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) - a compiler specific keyword. Not clear if it needs to be before or after the `*`.

Comment: @Nonanon I am using Mingw with gcc version 4.9

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I honestly don't know if what I was googling would have gave good answers or not, so please bare with me. I'm not sure exactly what the code is either, Just that they were in the source, not a header. I'm probably just as confused as you :(

Comment: Fair enough. This does not look like valid C++ code to me, even after making allowances for the aforementioned Microsoftese.

Comment: The code looks valid to me, as long as windows.h is included. I don't know where you're getting that __attribute__ from though, if this code is meant for windows.

Comment: @Nonanon  The aim is to bring NtAlocateVirtualMemory and NtCreateThreadEx into the program, i have other things that i took that are used right along with the posted typedefs, should I edit and include those? EDIT: when I changed the NTSTATUS to long, it compiled, still don't know if it will run, and I'm still not even sure how to use them yet, I'm still super early into writing this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik

Comment: @Nonanon I think I was able to solve it, I'll admit, I'm embarrassed. I had to do typedef long NTSTATUS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `NTSTATUS` is defined in the Windows SDK header file *winternl.h*:

```
typedef _Return_type_success_(return >= 0) LONG NTSTATUS;
```

You need to include that header file instead of trying to define `NTSTATUS` yourself. The SDK provided definition differs in two ways: `1` It contains SAL annotations that allow you do run static code analysis. `2` It provides the correct alias, irrespective of platform. It should be a 32-bit integer value on both x86 and x64 platforms. `long` may be longer than that.

Comment: Thank you, The program was working once I added that definition so I didn't think I needed to add anything else, I'll change that right away.

Comment: Alright, I'm using Netbeans with Mingw, winternl.h couldn't be imported, any suggestions?

Comment: @JayM.: I don't know, what *"winternl.h couldn't be imported"* is supposed to mean. Header files are included. Without a better problem statement, there's little help to be had.

Comment: The header file couldn't be included, doesn't look like it's there. I'm not sure what else I can provide in terms of information, I'm doing some googling. I can't seem to find it.

Comment: *winternl.h* is part of the Windows SDK. Make sure you have properly installed the SDK, and set up your build environment. MinGW is known to be flaky. If you can, consider using a build environment with official support (such as [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/)).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was incredibly simple. To the header I added:

```
typedef long NTSTATUS;
```

It seems to have compiled correctly, and one of the functions works fine from my understanding. I thank those who helped for sending me on the right thought process and in the right direction a TON :).

Edit:
By using visual studios, i have access to winternl.h, where NTSTATUS is properly defined, my original answer is not a solution.

Comment: No. You need to include the file that defines NTSTATUS.

Comment: You are correct, I edited my statement to include what ended up working for me, and working properly.